# Get processor architecture from Node

Tags: node.js

I know that I can get the OS details using process.platform or with the os Module, but I'd also like to know if the OS is a 32 or 64 bit flavor.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `process.env['MACHTYPE']` or `process.env['HOSTTYPE']`. If either are `undefined`, then check with `uname -m` (that is supposed to work on all POSIX systems,
though the output can be any string in fact, [*see uname(1P)*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uname.html)).

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, arch;

exec('uname -m', function (error, stdout, stderr) { 
  if (error) throw error;
  arch = stdout;
});
```

Well, may be it's not quite as brief as you wish, however you would probably find a plenty of shell scripts which do just that for whatever system you are running on and you can just run such script instead. That way you will have just one thing to run and check the output of from your Node app.

Another solution would be to write a module for Node in C++ which would check for low-level system features, including the endianess  and whatever else one might need to check. There plenty of example on how to check such things.

Comment: `process.env['PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE']`

Answer (score 25):

It's far easier than that, just use `process.arch`. It'll return `x64` or `x32` depending on the architecture.

Comment: returns `ia32` for me - see https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_arch

Comment: also, `process.arch` returns `arm` on a raspberry pi (and presumably other arm devices)

Comment: “The `process.arch` property returns a string identifying the operating system CPU architecture **for which the Node.js binary was compiled**.” And you can run 32-bit Node.js on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 12):

You simply run on your terminal this code:

```sh
node -e "console.log(process.arch)"
```

This will return the architecture of your Node build. It's very useful to check if you are running inside Rosetta 2 on MacOS.

Comment: Another way to do this is to run `node -p 'process.arch'`

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are running in a linux-like system you can use the process module to run 'uname -i'.  If the output contains '64' there's a good chance you are on a 64-bit system.

This won't always work.

Any particular reason you want to detect this?  Perhaps another approach would be better.

Comment: I need to know what particular version of a dependency I need to download. (e.g. mongoDB 32-bit or 64-bit, and yes, I'm aware of the problems with mongoDB 32-bit)

Comment: Well in that case the uname -i approach would probably work.  Depending on how you launch your app you could save the trouble of fussing with node's process / pipe system and put the uname output into an environment variable.